# Variation of the Einstein Hilbert Action (Tensor Algebra)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus, action, variational-calculus

I'm struggling a bit with the algebra involved in deriving the variance of the Einstein Hilbert Action.

I have that:

$$\delta R^{\lambda}_{\mu \alpha \nu} = \nabla_{\alpha}\delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \mu} - \nabla_{\nu} \delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\alpha \mu}$$

$$\implies g^{\mu \nu}\delta R_{\mu \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} R^{\lambda}_{\mu \lambda \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\alpha}\delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \mu} - g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\nu} \delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\alpha \mu}$$

Now here I should see that this is equivalent to:

$$\nabla_{\lambda}(\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \mu} g^{\mu \nu} - g^{\lambda \alpha} \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\sigma \alpha})$$

However I'm struggling to see how

$$ g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\nu} \delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\alpha \mu} = \nabla_{\lambda} g^{\lambda \alpha} \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\sigma \alpha}$$

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your last equation doesn't make sense, indices are wrong. On the l.h.s. you have free indices $\lambda$ and $\alpha$, on the r.h.s. there are no free indices.

Comment: Oh thanks, I realise my error now. I wasn't substituting   for , in the equation for the variation of the Riemann tensor

Answer (score 1):

It was because in my second line of working I did not contract the first and third indices in my equation for the variation of the Riemann tensor.

It should look like this

$$\implies g^{\mu \nu}\delta R_{\mu \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} R^{\lambda}_{\mu \lambda \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\lambda}\delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \mu} - g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\nu} \delta \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda \mu}$$

Which is clearly equivalent to the next line (can switch the variable we are summing over to anything).